# string.substring(int start,int end) doesnwt work as supposed to

Tags: android

I am trying to split a substring from a string without using split method, like this:

```
    private String getSequence(String what, String start, String end){
        return what.substring(what.indexOf(start), what.indexOf(end));
    }
```

For example I use string `"<_id 2211 _id>"` like this:

```
  getSequence("<_id 2211 _id>","<_id 2211 _id>".indexOf("<_id ","<_id 2211 _id>".indexOf(" _id>")
```

My expected output is `" 2211 "` but the actual output is `"<_id 2211 "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change you return from

```
  return what.substring(what.indexOf(start), what.indexOf(end));
```

To

```
return what.substring(what.indexOf(start) + start.length(), what.indexOf(end));
```

As [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) will return you 0 in your case as that's where it found matching String "<_id "

Note aside: Make sure if pattern doesnt exist in your string then index of will return you -1 and may throw StringIndexOutOfBoundException or may give unexpected result as well as you will now be doing addition. So you should validate it before hand that both indexOf doesnt return you -1.

Comment: oh, thats right thanks alot mate, i will accept asap

Answer (score 0):

Change the first parameter of substring to `what.indexOf(start) + start.lenght()`. I‘ll leave it to you to figure out how this sollution works.